# View files in iCloud (without Pages) for iOS app testing?

Tags: filesystems, icloud

I am working on an app right now that is supposed to generate a text document from an NSString , save it to the app's documents foldr, and then upload it to the iCloud.

I have confirmed that a .txt file is being created with the data I want, and is then stored inside the Documents folder in my app's Sandbox on the device. My next step is to debug the iCloud upload. It looks like my app is failing to upload the document to iCloud, by looking at `Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backups > ManageStorage > myAppName > files created by my app in the iCloud would be listed here`.

So, to confirm this, I want to view my entire iCloud account as a normal directory of files, and look for the file I am supposed to be creating & uploading with my app. Think about how Dropbox displays their files. That's what I'm talking about.

`How do you view all the raw files saved in your personal iCloud, as if it were a normal filesystem?` (I cannot purchase Pages at this time.)

Update: I have now gotten my text file's name to appear in the Settings > iCloud > etc... but I still do not have a way to verify it exists in my iCloud, nor view the file's contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.icloud.com will show you what the iCloud server thinks your app container looks like. It will also let you download the files.

However, note that iOS devices also sync peer-to-peer, so the iCloud server might not have the very latest information all the time.

Comment: This sounds awesome, but I can't access the site. I have an iOS developer account, with a working iPhone app in-progress that uses iCloud and iOS 5.0+, but logging in produces the error: "This Apple ID does not have developer access to iCloud.com. To use developer.icloud.com, first sign in to iCloud with latest iOS." And trying to pull up the site on the phone with mobile Safari doesn't even have the option to log in. (It tells me to set up iCloud on the device, but that is already done).

Comment: If you have an iOS developer account, then you should be able to install the latest iOS beta on your device. This will let you access this site.

Comment: I'm using the existing iOS 5.1, so then you have to use iOS 6 to access the developer.icloud.com via mobile safari?

Comment: This is awesome! I need to see all iCloud containers and here they are. To login you have to use your *regular* account i.e. Apple ID.